# Salesforce Chat / Live Agent / Basic test isn't showing button

Tags: liveagent, chat

So I have followed the setup flow and hopefully configured the Live Agent Chat properly.  I have copied the deployment code and the button code into a blank html file and loaded it into a browser.

When I set my omni channel status to offline I can correctly see the text I have set as the offline text.  However when I choose to go online simply nothing is displayed (the offline text dissapears as expected).

Has anyone run through the chat documentation recently, am I following old procedure or something?

I have checked my user account (chat enabled), enabled chat, set up agent configuration, button, settings and the deployment.  We are using omni channel so i've set up the presence status and routing alongside skills (although I can replicate the functionality when using or not using skill based routing).

The code on the page is simply:

```
 <a id="liveagent_button_online_IDGOESHERE" href="javascript://Chat" style="display: none;" onclick="liveagent.startChat('IDGOESHERE')"> ONLINE CHAT LINK</a><div id="liveagent_button_offline_IDGOESHERE" style="display: none;"> OFFLINE CHAT TEXT</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    if (!window._laq) { window._laq = []; }
    window._laq.push(function(){liveagent.showWhenOnline('IDGOESHERE', document.getElementById('liveagent_button_online_IDGOESHERE'));
    liveagent.showWhenOffline('IDGOESHERE', document.getElementById('liveagent_button_offline_IDGOESHERE'));
    });</script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://c.la1-c2-lo2.salesforceliveagent.com/content/g/js/47.0/deployment.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    liveagent.init('https://d.la1-c2-lo2.salesforceliveagent.com/chat', 'IDGOESHERE', 'IDGOESHERE');</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately it came down to something obvious... We had disabled "Chat User" on our Admin accounts in preparation for going live, the user accounts were the only ones enabled.  Once the permissions had been corrected it worked fine.